# What is more secure, HMAC with SHA-1, or with SHA-256 and take a substring?

Tags: sha-256, sha-1

I'm going to guess the latter, but just wanted to ask here.

I want to have a relatively short signature, and my goal is to take a substring of the resulting hash.

Comment: Duplicate of [HMAC-SHA1 vs HMAC-SHA256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/hmac-sha1-vs-hmac-sha256) and [HMAC-SHA1 vs HMAC-SHA256 for data storage](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/differences-between-using-hmac-sha1-vs-hmac-sha256-for-data-storage). In sum, use HMAC-SHA-256 because SHA-1 shouldn't be used for any new protocols, but HMAC-SHA-1 [isn't](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/why-is-hmac-sha1-still-considered-secure) broken.

Comment: HMAC doesn't depend on collision resistance of the hash used, so HMAC-SHA1 isn't insecure. However, as a general practice, it's always better to HMAC-SHA256 for newer implementations

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 Neither directly addresses the substring issue, although it is mentioned in one of the comments in the first question. That said, taking a substring from a well distributed randomized value doesn't alter the strength of the algorithm. Uh, maybe that's the answer :)

Comment: Are you asking about HMAC-SHA1 with a 160-bit tag vs plain SHA-256 truncated to 160 bits?

Comment: yes that's what I meant